# How to use variables in substitution with vim regular expressions

Tags: text-processing, vim, regular-expression

I have a big file that contains among others serveral lines of the following form:

```
USet07-1
USet07-2
USet08-1
USet08-2
.
.
.
USet22-2
.
.
.
```

I want to remove the hyphen/dash `-` from these strings in `vim`. I search for the strings with:

```
:/USet\d\d-\d
```

but when I try to replace these with

```
:%s/Uset\d\d-\d/USet\d\d\d
```

I obviously get

```
USetddd
```

for all instances. But what I want is:

```
USet071
USet072
USet081
USet082
.
.
.
USet222
.
.
.
```

How can this be done? Can I reuse parts of the matched string and use it in the substitution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can, with *capture groups*. Basically, you wrap the parts of the pattern with `\(...\)` and reference that in the replacement part with `\1` etc.:

```
:%s/Uset\(\d\d\)-\(\d\)/USet\1\2
```

Since you only want to *remove* a single part of the pattern, a shorter option is restricting the actual match (but still asserting that the stuff around is also there) via `\zs` (match start) and `\ze` (match end):

```
:%s/Uset\d\d\zs-\ze\d//
```

These are all very basic things, and capture groups are common in many regular expression-based tools (like `sed`). Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself using substring matching thanks to the `vim` help:

```
:%s/\(USet\d\d\)-\(\d\)/\1\2/gc
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex can be easier to work with if you use the `\v` pattern prefix. With that, you don't have to escape `(`, `{`, `[` and more.

```
:%s/\vUSet(\d\d)-(\d)/USet\1\2/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using sed command

sed "/^USet/s/-//" filename >outputfile

Suppose if you want to perform on orginal file

sed -i "/^USet/s/-//" filename
```

output

```
USet071
USet072
USet081
USet082
```

awk command

```
awk '/^USe/{sub("-","",$0);print }' filename >outfile

output

USet071
USet072
USet081
USet082
```